# How to match and replace templating tags in Ruby / Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, templates

Trying to add a very rudimentary description template to one of my Rails models. What I want to do is take a template string like this:

```
template = "{{ name }} is the best {{ occupation }} in {{ city }}."
```

and a hash like this:

```
vals = {:name => "Joe Smith", :occupation => "birthday clown", :city => "Las Vegas"}
```

and get a description generated. I thought I could do this with a simple gsub but Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't accept hashes as the second argument. When I do a gsub as a block like this:

```
> template.gsub(/\{\{\s*(\w+)\s*\}\}/) {|m| vals[m]}
=> " is the best  in ."
```

You can see it replaces it with the entire string (with curly braces), not the match captures.

How do I get it to replace "{{ something }}" with vals["something"] (or vals["something".to_sym])?

TIA

Answer (score 24):

### Using Ruby 1.9.2

The [string formatting operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-M001127) `%` will format a string with a hash as the *arg*

```
>> template = "%{name} is the best %{occupation} in %{city}."
>> vals = {:name => "Joe Smith", :occupation => "birthday clown", :city => "Las Vegas"}
>> template % vals
=> "Joe Smith is the best birthday clown in Las Vegas."
```

---

### Using Ruby 1.8.7

[The string formatting operator in Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't support hashes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000742). Instead, you can use the same arguments as the Ruby 1.9.2 solution and patch the String object so when you upgrade Ruby you won't have to edit your strings.

```
if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.2'
  class String
    old_format = instance_method(:%)

    define_method(:%) do |arg|
      if arg.is_a?(Hash)
        self.gsub(/%\{(.*?)\}/) { arg[$1.to_sym] }
      else
        old_format.bind(self).call(arg)
      end
    end
  end
end

>> "%05d" % 123 
=> "00123"
>> "%-5s: %08x" % [ "ID", 123 ]
=> "ID   : 0000007b"
>> template = "%{name} is the best %{occupation} in %{city}."
>> vals = {:name => "Joe Smith", :occupation => "birthday clown", :city => "Las Vegas"}
>> template % vals
=> "Joe Smith is the best birthday clown in Las Vegas."
```

### [codepad example showing the default and extended behavior](http://codepad.org/cYx7ejUm)

Comment: I'm on Ruby 1.8.7 but that's pretty awesome nonetheless.

Comment: @Callmeed I've added a Ruby 1.8.7 answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is probably to use `$1.to_sym` in your block:

```
>> template.gsub(/\{\{\s*(\w+)\s*\}\}/) { vals[$1.to_sym] }
=> "Joe Smith is the best birthday clown in Las Vegas."
```

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186):

> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $’ will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

Comment: I saw that in the manual but was still confused. So what exactly does the variable $1 correspond to? Thanks a bunch, though, your solution works for Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: @Callmeed: The numbered globals (`$1`, `$2`, ...) represent the capture groups from the last regex match, things inside parentheses, such as the `(\w+)`, are captured so that they can be referenced elsewhere. The groups are numbered from left to right by their opening parenthesis so `$1` is what your `\w+` matched.